# Nginx reverse proxy: How to get access to different container via subdomains?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

This is how I configured my reverse proxy using nginx. There are docker container with nodeJS applications running (app1, app2, ...)

With this I point via `localhost:8080` to the docker container app1 nodeJS application and with `localhost:8081` to app2.

But I want to call the apps via subdomains without using the ports and I don't see how do get this. I also think I messed up the ports...

`app1.localhost` should point to `app1` and `app2.localhost` should point to `app2`.

*nginx.conf*

```
http {
  sendfile on;

  upstream docker-app1 {
    server app1:80;
  }

  upstream docker-app2 {
    server app2:80;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name app1.localhost;
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://docker-app1;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_buffering    off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      #proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 8081;
    server_name app2.localhost;
    location / {
      proxy_pass         http://docker-app2;
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_buffering    off;
      proxy_set_header   Host $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      #proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    }
  }
}
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nginx:
    container_name: 'nginx'
    image: 'nginx:1.13.5'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '8080:8080'
      - '8081:8081'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - './nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro'

  app1:
    container_name: app1
    build: ./app1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '3001:80'

  app2:
    container_name: app2
    build: ./app1
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '4200:80'
```

*Update: As Sergiu provided a good link for reverse proxy, I updated the post with the new configuration; the question is still the same*

Comment: So u wanna access localhost:8081 as http://app.local?

Comment: does something stops you from using port 80?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do it that way but you could defo have http://app.local:8081 if that's ok

Comment: you are missing the application from your nginx config...i cannot see anywhere where u are pointing to the application directory in your nginx default.conf

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I just have the docker-compose file which runs the application. But with that it is not accessable at all. You are right, the nginx config for that is missing. And that is my question, as I do not understand it correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156781/discussion-between-sergiu-and-user3142695).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of a custom nginx, using [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy/) should be sufficient:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro

  app1:
    container_name: app1
    build: ./app1
    restart: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: app1.localhost
    ports:
      - 80

  app2:
    container_name: app2
    build: ./app1
    restart: always
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: app2.localhost
    ports:
      - 80
```

Then put this in the `/etc/host` of your machine:

```
127.0.0.1 app1.localhost
127.0.0.1 app2.localhost
```

Use as this:

```
curl -i app1.localhost
```

`jwilder/nginx-proxy` will do the magic reading the `VIRTUAL_HOST` environment variable from each container (through the docket API), and then set up its config files accordingly.

Comment: I'm using macOS and I don't know where to find `docker.sock``

Comment: Thanks for this great working example. Only one question left - as I don't understand the readme for this point: How do I add SSL support? I got some selfsigned certificates locally and I would like to switch to `https://app1.localhost`. On my productive server I will use letsenrypt.

Comment: Very cool way to deploy 2 sub domain on same server

Comment: does it work if jwilder-nginx is in different folder/docker-compose.yaml file?

Answer (score 1):

Build and run doesn't work in version 3.x

create the docker images for your node applications.

Dockerfile for creating the images of node application

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:boron

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json .
# For npm@5 or later, copy package-lock.json as well
# COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Replcae the EXPOSE port accordingly

create the docker images

> docker build -t app1 .
>
> docker build -t app2 .

**Create the hosts**

> sudo echo "127.0.0.1 app1.localhost" >> /etc/hosts
>
> sudo echo "127.0.0.1 app2.localhost" >> /etc/hosts

**nginx.conf**

```
user root;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include            mime.types;
    default_type       application/octet-stream;
    sendfile           on;
    tcp_nopush         on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip               on;
    gzip_types         text/plain text/css text/javascript
                       application/javascript application/json
                       application/xml;
    index              index.html index.htm;  

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name server_name app1.localhost;;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.42.174:8081/; 
        # Replace 172.31.42.174 with localhost if you are running reverse proxy in local server user private ip/public ip
        # Add other properties as required
      }
    }  

    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name server_name app2.localhost;;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.31.42.174:8081/;
                # Replace 172.31.42.174 with localhost if you are running reverse proxy in local server user private ip/public ip
                # Add other properties as required
      }
    }  
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        image: 'nginx:1.13.5'

        ports:
            - '80:80'
        volumes:
            - nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 2
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]

    app1:
        image: app1
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 2
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
    app2:
        image: app2
        ports:
            - 8081:8081
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 2
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure

volumes:
  nginx-conf:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /path/of/nginx/conf/nginx.conf
```

give full path of the nfginx.conf to the volume, as nginx is conf file dependent we need to run nginx at master node.

**RUN**

docker stack deploy -c docker-compose nodeapps

**Status**

> docker stack ls
>
> docker service ls

Comment: I am not sure whether the question asks for `docker stack`. I think that it is about plain docker-compose, in which `build` is totally legal. Also, pointing to `localhost` from the nginx config won't work because each container has its own `localhost`.